# If 2 heal spells overlap then is healing rate doubled

Tags: clash-of-clans

Title explains my question:

If 2 heal spells overlap then is healing rate doubled?

Comment: Is the healing spell effect a pulse or a constant effect?

Comment: Probably it is constant healing. Research lab says total heal is 1300

Comment: Effects last for 12 seconds

Comment: Hey wait. On the page where memorx referenced it has given that heal spell does pulse healing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Effect is increased according to the Wikia

> You can stack Healing Spells on top of each other to increase the effect.

Source: [Healing Spell - Trivia](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Spell)

However the spell itself is a Pulse as the same page lists at it has 40 pulses and each upgrade increase the amount of HP each pulse will heal.

this means the increased effects is caused by the unit being in a area where the pulses from the spells will reach him, if you think about it as a Venn Diagram

[image]

If a unit is in the Magenta, Turquoise of Yellow Areas they'll only get 2 hits, if they are in the white area they'll get all 3.

Answer (score 0):

If its a constant spell, no, if a pulse, yes

Comment: There is always a possibility that it does stack if it's constant. It's just definite that it will if it's a pulse

Comment: That is true ben.. Didnt think of that